# add openweathermap png tile layers on mapbox style

Tags: qt, styles, mapbox, openweathermap

I'm trying to implement openweathermap map weather layers from https://openweathermap.org/api/weathermaps on a mapbox map style but i don't know where to put the image tile source on the json file. can i have some help? 
thank you. I'm using Mapbox for Qt and here is my code, i'm using Mapbox maps for Qt, and here is my QML code

```
   MapParameter {
                id: source
                type: "source"
                property var name: "weatherSource"
                property var sourceType: "raster"
                property var url: "https://tile.openweathermap.org/"
property var tiles:  
["https://tile.openweathermap.org/map/clouds_new/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?appid=API_ID"]
                property var tileSize: 256
                property var scheme: "xyz"
                property var minzoom: 4.0
                property var maxzoom: 20.0}
   MapParameter {
                type: "layer"
                property var name: "wind_weather"
                property var layerType: "raster"
                property var source: "weatherSource"}
```

Comment: Could you share which version of the Mapbox Maps SDK are you using?

Comment: @jmkiley here is the code

Answer (score 0):

support for source "tiles" property has not been implemented yet. I'm going to open a ticket in https://bugreports.qt.io about this feature request - thanks!